# https action in Struts

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I am using `html:form` `action = "someAction"` to refer to an action in struts-config file. I wanted to make that action as https but apparently I cannot replace an absolute path like https://webserver/context/abc.do with `someAction` in `html:form`. Just wondering is there a property or parameter I can set to make that form submission to an https url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do something like that with Struts 1.x, you will need to use [sslext](http://sslext.sourceforge.net/) extension to do so. Here's an example: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Securing-Struts-Applications/7/